# Where to store the users' personal data in windows8

Tags: windows-8

I want to develop a personal finance software in windows8, users can login by facebook or twitter account, where can I store users' data? Should I have a server or some other safe place can store the personal finance data?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use the Azure cloud service, it looks very simple to add to windows store apps http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started/.

Also data security is MUCH harder than you first think, I'd consider making sure the data is encrypted wherever its stored as this is so sensitive.